# How to modify the scheduler of an Android OS to enable a GTS scheduling?

Tags: android, arm, kernel, openmp, scheduling

I hope this question is relevant in SO. I posted it in Android forums like XDA Developers but I don't get any answers and at the same time, I believe my question is specific and it is hard to target people that might know something about it.

To introduce the context of my question, I think I will need to describe a bit of my job. I am currently working in a company that needs to transform a phone into IOT device that run our C/C++ library (like [JanOS](http://janos.io/)). The idea is to modify a phone to take off the screen and only keep its board with all its features (camera, wifi, sdcard, battery, usb connector ...) that we needs. 
I am myself a C/C++ developer and I optimize algorithms. My work is basically to make everything faster using libraries like OpenMP and NEON if I work on an Android platform. I am currently working on two phones that are rooted:

- Huawei Honor 5C (4x2.0 GHz Cortex-A53 & 4x1.7 GHz Cortex-A53)
- Huawei Honor 8 (4x2.3 GHz Cortex-A72 & 4x1.8 GHz Cortex A53)

I want to bench the library we are developing in my company on these phones. The thing is I can never get to 100% CPU usage using C code or bash script. The CPU usage cannot go higher than 50% letting me think only 4 cores are used. This is where I tried to understood more the platform. I think each phone is based on a big.LITTLE ARM platform to optimize battery saving (I have a doubt about the Honor 5C as it contains two identical cores running at different speed only). The idea is to build 4 group of 2 cores (1 big and 1 LITTLE) so the scheduler can target the right CPU to use depending on the task needs. But my aim is to overcome that and use ALL the cores like a classic multicore platform.

OpenMP can see 8 cores in my platform. But it seems the phone cannot let the thread migrate from 1 group of cores to another. My guess is the cores being seen as pairs by the scheduler, only 1 of them can work even though OpenMP can see 8 cores. I think Global Task Scheduler is disabled and it could overcome if I understood it well. But I'm not an expert of Android development so I might be wrong here.

Do anyone has any idea how I could enable the Global Task Scheduler ? How can I even know if it available in my platform and if it is really disabled ? Or how could I setup my OpenMP pragmas to use 8 cores at once ?

I basically tried to activate the "Performance mode" directly in the phones settings, but it didn't work. That would be too simple

**[EDIT]**

I went through interesting information lately. I will share them with you as someone might be interested by them and might help me with the kernel building.

I found this git in the [OpenKirin project](https://github.com/OpenKirin/android_kernel_honor_berlin) which I think helps building a custom Android kernel. At least I can see the `arm64` architecture among the ones possible to configure.

I also saw there is a guard checked called `CONFIG_SCHED_HMP` which seems to enable the Heterogeneous Multi-Processing scheduling which I think is the subject of my question.

This `CONFIG_SCHED_HMP` should depend on the configuration. I think the one under `arch/arm64/` called `Kconfig` is the one I should modify and it seems the `SCHED_HMP`configuration isn't activated.

Comment: _"a company that needs to transform a phone into IOT device... The idea is to modify a phone to take off the screen and only keep its board with all its features (camera, wifi, sdcard, battery, usb connector ...)"_ Is your company aware of [Android Things project](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/index.html)? Though, the boards supported have a bit ["lower" characteristics](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html) compare to the one you've mentioned... As to _"Global Task Scheduler"_, sorry, can't say anything helpful.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, it has lots of redundant description. Here, on SO, you should tend [to ask a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to avoid closing it.

Comment: I know this question is really on the edge of SO. I agree this might not the best place for it. But I couldn't figure where to ask. The Android community didn't seem more appropriate. I hope I will find interested people here

Comment: The reason is that your two phones may have older Android OS while the Linux kernel is a bit older. Based on your description, your kernel may use the Kernel Switcher scheduling method. For ARM big.LITTLE Architecture, HMP scheduling and Energy Awareness Scheduling can allow you to see the total eight CPUs in your case. HMP and EAS are only supported in newer Kernel release.  So it's better for find if there are latest Android ROM for the two phones released by phone manufacturer.